# Как получить адрес выбранного объекта на карте в Yandex Mapkit?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Я использую geoObjectTapListener, который мне возвращает GeoObjectTapEvent и с него я уже получаю GeoObject и метадату по нему. Из метадаты я могу получить id объекта. Я попробовал использовать метод searchByURI в классе SearchManager, преобразовав id объекта в uri с помощью ResourceUrlProvider, только в ответ на запрос ничего не находит. То есть в Response на запрос по uri ничего нету. Пробовал ещё как-то по другому получить адрес, но не получилось. Мне нужно получить адрес выбранного объекта. Как это сделать?

Comment: 1. Чисто для уточнения вопроса - речь о ваших геообъектах или о POI изначально присутствующих на карте? 2. Раньше выходила полезная статья на Хабре по поиске в МапКите. Там есть и про обратный поиск, может поможет: https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/428564/ 3. Если есть минимальный пример кода, всегда можно запросить помощи в поддержке Яндекса, может подскажут, куда копать.

Comment: @YaCor' Большое спасибо! Такая ужасная у Яндекса документация, чтобы я без вас делал.